# How to generate a sequence that corresponds for True and False

Tags: r

So what I want to do is a create a sequence in a dataframe that progresses from 1, but whenever it encounters TRUE's based on another column, it matches those up if they are in sequential rows.

For example, in this dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(date = c("11","12", "13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21", "22", "23"), 
    flag = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE))
```

I want this as the output:

```
df <- data.frame(date = c("11","12", "13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21", "22", "23"), 
             flag = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE),
             id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 9, 10))
```

Keep in mind that the dates being in sequential order is just an example as I am working with a big dataset so they will not coordinate at all. Also, the flag column is just one column in a dataframe with dozens more columns

Answer (score 3):

Here is one option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
i1 <- setDT(df)[, grp := rleid(flag)][, .I[flag & (seq_len(.N)==1)], grp]$V1
df[, flag1:= flag][i1, flag1 := FALSE][, id := cumsum(!flag1)][, c('flag1', 'grp') := NULL][]
#    date  flag id
# 1:   11 FALSE  1
# 2:   12 FALSE  2
# 3:   13 FALSE  3
# 4:   14  TRUE  4
# 5:   15  TRUE  4
# 6:   16 FALSE  5
# 7:   17 FALSE  6
# 8:   18  TRUE  7
# 9:   19  TRUE  7
#10:   20  TRUE  7
#11:   21 FALSE  8
#12:   22 FALSE  9
1#3:   23 FALSE 10
```

Comment: Thanks, but looking for a none data table answer since my dataset is pretty big and using data tables slow it down considerably

Comment: @Ic3MaN911  data.table is used for big datasets and is very efficient.  Perhaps you are looking for data.frame solution (which would be slow)